# pandas: how to get current datetime for NaT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to calculate ageing, by doing difference of 2 dynamic dates and converting this into respective hours

here is my code snippet

```
l_series = getattr(df, field_def['primaryField'])
r_series = getattr(df, field_def['secondaryField'])
result = l_series - r_series
```

here is my output

```
4                          NaT
14   2020-03-02 13:59:11+00:00
```

I could understand there is no field `updated_at` for first record and this is why this is throwing NaT.

Is there a way I can replace the NaT with the current datetime?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to fill the NaT with the current datetime?  Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @tnknepp yes...

Answer (score 3):

First idea is replace only by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html), but because different timezones output is object:

```
result1 = result.fillna(pd.to_datetime('now'))
print (result1)
4     2020-03-13 10:33:10.557126
14     2020-03-02 13:59:11+00:00
Name: s, dtype: object
```

For `datetime`s with timezones add [`Timestamp.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.tz_localize.html):

```
result2 = result.fillna(pd.to_datetime('now').tz_localize('utc'))
print (result2)
4    2020-03-13 10:33:10.559126+00:00
14          2020-03-02 13:59:11+00:00
Name: s, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```